# getting repeated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not able to get why i am getting repeated data for below query. Although i have used distinct.

The query is as below- Please help :
Might be some problem with joins

```
SELECT DISTINCT(UM.USERNAME)'USER_NAME'
        ,UM.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + UM.LASTNAME AS 'EMPLOYEE NAME'
        ,US.USER_NAME 'USER_ID'
        ,US.MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST_KEY
        ,RG.REPORTING_GROUP_NAME
        ,US.MS_RIT_REGION_MST_KEY
        ,RM.REGION_NAME
        ,US.MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST_KEY
        ,SM.SUB_REGION_NAME
        ,TP.TASK_MST_KEY
        ,TTM.TASK_TYPE_NAME
        ,CT.*
        ,FM.TASK_STATUS
        ,FM.TASK_START_DATE
        ,FM.TASK_END_DATE
        ,SRM.ROLE_NAME AS ROLENAME
    FROM USERS_MASTER UM
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_USER_SKILLSET_MAP US ON UM.USERID = US.USER_NAME
    INNER JOIN DIM_MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST RG ON US.MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST_KEY = RG.MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST_KEY
        AND UPPER(RG.ACTIVE) IN ('YES','1','Y')
    INNER JOIN DIM_MS_RIT_REGION_MST RM ON US.MS_RIT_REGION_MST_KEY = RM.MS_RIT_REGION_MST_KEY
        AND UPPER(RM.ACTIVE) IN ('YES','1','Y')
    INNER JOIN DIM_MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST SM ON US.MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST_KEY = SM.MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST_KEY
        AND UPPER(SM.ACTIVE) IN ('YES','1','Y')
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_USER_TASK_MAP TP ON CONVERT(VARCHAR,UM.USERID) = TP.USER_ID
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_CREATE_TASK CT ON CT.TASK_ID = TP.TASK_MST_KEY
    INNER JOIN WF_FRM_28_MST FM ON FM.TASK_ID = CT.TASK_ID
    INNER JOIN SEC_USER_ROLE SR ON SR.USER_ID = UM.USERNAME
    INNER JOIN SEC_ROLE_MST SRM ON SRM.ROLE_CODE = SR.ROLE_CODE
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_TASK_TYPE_MASTER TTM ON CT.TASK_TYPE = TTM.TASK_TYPE_ID
```

Comment: Are you certain that the "duplicate" rows you are seeing are actually duplicate?  Perhaps they differ by whitespace or some other formatting?

Comment: Well, there is no such thing as `DISTINCT` on 1 column, so as long as 1 of the columns is different, it won't work. Some sample data could help us understand, but probably its because one or more of this tables contain more then one record for each user.

Answer (score 0):

### Use UNION to get rid of duplicates

One solution to check if you have duplicates is to do a UNION using the same query, if no rows were removed then they are not duplicates.

```
(SELECT DISTINCT(UM.USERNAME)'USER_NAME'
        ,UM.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + UM.LASTNAME AS 'EMPLOYEE NAME'
        ,US.USER_NAME 'USER_ID'
        ,US.MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST_KEY
        ,RG.REPORTING_GROUP_NAME
        ,US.MS_RIT_REGION_MST_KEY
        ,RM.REGION_NAME
        ,US.MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST_KEY
        ,SM.SUB_REGION_NAME
        ,TP.TASK_MST_KEY
        ,TTM.TASK_TYPE_NAME
        ,CT.*
        ,FM.TASK_STATUS
        ,FM.TASK_START_DATE
        ,FM.TASK_END_DATE
        ,SRM.ROLE_NAME AS ROLENAME
    FROM USERS_MASTER UM
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_USER_SKILLSET_MAP US ON UM.USERID = US.USER_NAME
    INNER JOIN DIM_MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST RG ON US.MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST_KEY = RG.MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST_KEY
        AND UPPER(RG.ACTIVE) IN ('YES','1','Y')
    INNER JOIN DIM_MS_RIT_REGION_MST RM ON US.MS_RIT_REGION_MST_KEY = RM.MS_RIT_REGION_MST_KEY
        AND UPPER(RM.ACTIVE) IN ('YES','1','Y')
    INNER JOIN DIM_MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST SM ON US.MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST_KEY = SM.MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST_KEY
        AND UPPER(SM.ACTIVE) IN ('YES','1','Y')
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_USER_TASK_MAP TP ON CONVERT(VARCHAR,UM.USERID) = TP.USER_ID
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_CREATE_TASK CT ON CT.TASK_ID = TP.TASK_MST_KEY
    INNER JOIN WF_FRM_28_MST FM ON FM.TASK_ID = CT.TASK_ID
    INNER JOIN SEC_USER_ROLE SR ON SR.USER_ID = UM.USERNAME
    INNER JOIN SEC_ROLE_MST SRM ON SRM.ROLE_CODE = SR.ROLE_CODE
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_TASK_TYPE_MASTER TTM ON CT.TASK_TYPE = TTM.TASK_TYPE_ID)

    UNION

(SELECT DISTINCT(UM.USERNAME)'USER_NAME'
        ,UM.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + UM.LASTNAME AS 'EMPLOYEE NAME'
        ,US.USER_NAME 'USER_ID'
        ,US.MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST_KEY
        ,RG.REPORTING_GROUP_NAME
        ,US.MS_RIT_REGION_MST_KEY
        ,RM.REGION_NAME
        ,US.MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST_KEY
        ,SM.SUB_REGION_NAME
        ,TP.TASK_MST_KEY
        ,TTM.TASK_TYPE_NAME
        ,CT.*
        ,FM.TASK_STATUS
        ,FM.TASK_START_DATE
        ,FM.TASK_END_DATE
        ,SRM.ROLE_NAME AS ROLENAME
    FROM USERS_MASTER UM
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_USER_SKILLSET_MAP US ON UM.USERID = US.USER_NAME
    INNER JOIN DIM_MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST RG ON US.MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST_KEY = RG.MS_RIT_REPORTING_GROUP_MST_KEY
        AND UPPER(RG.ACTIVE) IN ('YES','1','Y')
    INNER JOIN DIM_MS_RIT_REGION_MST RM ON US.MS_RIT_REGION_MST_KEY = RM.MS_RIT_REGION_MST_KEY
        AND UPPER(RM.ACTIVE) IN ('YES','1','Y')
    INNER JOIN DIM_MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST SM ON US.MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST_KEY = SM.MS_RIT_SUB_REGION_MST_KEY
        AND UPPER(SM.ACTIVE) IN ('YES','1','Y')
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_USER_TASK_MAP TP ON CONVERT(VARCHAR,UM.USERID) = TP.USER_ID
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_CREATE_TASK CT ON CT.TASK_ID = TP.TASK_MST_KEY
    INNER JOIN WF_FRM_28_MST FM ON FM.TASK_ID = CT.TASK_ID
    INNER JOIN SEC_USER_ROLE SR ON SR.USER_ID = UM.USERNAME
    INNER JOIN SEC_ROLE_MST SRM ON SRM.ROLE_CODE = SR.ROLE_CODE
    INNER JOIN MS_RIT_TASK_TYPE_MASTER TTM ON CT.TASK_TYPE = TTM.TASK_TYPE_ID)
```

Comment: Yes it's not performance wise, but should get rid of duplicates if they exist.